# Error while running sudo apt-get command

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

When I try to run `sudo apt-get` command I'm getting

```
> Reading package lists... Done W: The repository
> 'https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu impish Release'
> does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a repository can't be
> authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. N: See
> apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
> details.
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE. Please [edit] and ask a question. I can think of more than one question your statements lead to. Why should I guess which one you're asking? Ask explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There are no packages for [Ubuntu Impish](https://packagecloud.io/app/ookla/speedtest-cli/search?q=&filter=all&filter=all&dist=ubuntu%2Fimpish), change the codename to `hirsute`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/impish/hirsute/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ookla_speedtest-cli.list
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed speedtest and there was still a sources.list file left behind that I removed like so:

```
sudo apt remove speedtest-cli
sudo rm  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ookla_speedtest-cli.list
```

After much frustration this solved my problems